# Model to XML file mapping - How to find location of deserialized object in soucre XML File.

Tags: c#, xml, mapping

Which is the best way to map my model to XML file using c# serializer. I mean that if for example I select an deserialized object I could be able to find the xml source text in XML file.

Comment: Xml source text? Any problem do you see in using DataContractSerializer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got a working sample for you and you can explore further on it.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;


namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
  public class Person
  {
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int XMLLine { get; set; }
  }
  public class Persons : List<Person> { }

  class Program
  {

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      //create your objects

      Person p = new Person();
      p.Age = 35;
      p.Name = "Arnold";

      Person p2 = new Person();
      p2.Age = 36;
      p2.Name = "Tom";

      Persons ps = new Persons();
      ps.Add(p);
      ps.Add(p2);

      //Serialize them to XML

      XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Persons));

      XDocument d = new XDocument();

      using (XmlWriter xw = d.CreateWriter())
        xs.Serialize(xw, ps);

      //print xml
      //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(d.ToString());

      // it will produce following xml. You can save it to file.
      //I have saved it to variable xml for demo



      string xml = @"<ArrayOfPerson>
                      <Person>
                        <Age>35</Age>
                        <Name>Arnold</Name>
                        <XMLLine>0</XMLLine>
                     </Person> 
                     <Person>
                       <Age>36</Age>
                       <Name>Tom</Name>
                       <XMLLine>0</XMLLine>
                      </Person>
                    </ArrayOfPerson>";




      XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml, LoadOptions.SetLineInfo);

      // A little trick to get xml line
      xdoc.Descendants("Person").All(a => { a.SetElementValue("XMLLine", ((IXmlLineInfo)a).HasLineInfo() ? ((IXmlLineInfo)a).LineNumber : -1); return true; });
      
      
      //deserialize back to object

      Persons pplz = xs.Deserialize((xdoc.CreateReader())) as Persons;

      pplz.All(a => { Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Name {0} ,Age{1} ,Line number of object in XML File {2}", a.Name, a.Age, a.XMLLine)); return true; });

      Console.ReadLine();

    }
  }
}
```

and It will give your results like

> Name Arnold ,Age35 ,Line number of object in XML File 2
>
> Name Tom ,Age36 ,Line number of object in XML File 7

---

Comment: use  d.Root.RemoveAttributes();  after   xs.Serialize(xw, ps); to remove all attributes from root node.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this extension method:

```
public static string ToXml<T>(this object obj)
{
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (TextWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream))
        {
            var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(streamWriter, obj);
            return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
        }
    }
}

public static void ToXmlFile<T>(this object obj, string fileName)
{
    using (TextWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fileName))
    {
        var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        xmlSerializer.Serialize(streamWriter, obj);
    }
}
```

USAGE:

```
// you will get this on a string variable
var xmlString = yourModel.ToXml<YourModel>();

// you will save our object in a file.
yourModel.ToXmlFile<YourModel>(@"C:\yourModelDump.xml");
```

Please be noted to add `SerializableAttribute` on your class

```
[Serializable]
public class YourModel
{
  //...
}
```

This should do it

Comment: it will just serialize my object and will give me the XML text this solution has a problem with duplicate nodes. But I need the mapping to the file. Something like give some command to serializer to store line position of each node in objects metadata.

Comment: Couldn't get you. Can you describe it in a bit details?

Comment: I mean that for example if I read an XML document with using mappings I would like to find in which line of XML document my current object is related. After I want to select my object from some kind of list and go to the XML file automatically in order to edit it.

Comment: Probably that is not available out of the box.